# How to use a variable value inside the calc function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add height of div using calc function . in jquery I  have a two variable . this variable value need to give inside the calc function i try like this way

```
    var x= $(".controlscroll").offset().top+25;
    var x1 = $(".rightSidIcons").offset().top+25

    $(".controlscroll").css('height', 'calc(100vh - x)');

    $(".rightSidIcons").css('height', 'calc(100vh - x1)');
```

But it is not getting  what is the mistake in my code can any one please change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(".controlscroll").css('height', 'calc(100vh - ' + x + 'px'));

$(".rightSidIcons").css('height', 'calc(100vh - ' + x1 + 'px'));
```